# Are there any "thin clients" that would allow me to run a Windows XP/7 app on an iPad with sound?

Tags: ipad, remote-desktop, windows

There are a number of remote access apps (from Citrix, etc.) that allow you to run Windows apps remotely on an iPad.

I need one that would allow me to remotely run (on an iPad) a Windows app with sound, so that I'd hear (on the iPad) the audio of the Windows app. Ideally it would also allow recording of sound on the iPad into the Windows program.

Comment: Microsoft's RDP protocol (which is what Windows uses to do desktop sharing) supports sending sound to the remote client, so any iPad app that supports RDP ought to, in theory, also allow you to hear the sound from the remote desktop. The Oracle Virtual Desktop Client for iPad (available in iTunes Store) also supports this, but it does require the remote desktop (Windows, Solaris or Linux) to be running on a Sun Ray server somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a good option.

Gives access to PC or Mac via iPad and plays audio/video.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/splashtop-remote-desktop-for/id402056323?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D2

*Update*:
I tried it and the sound works great in Windows 7 (and I suspect Visa) and above. The sound will work on Windows XP as well but , IIRC, you get sound thru the app AND through the PC, which means that if the PC is nearby (the case in my scenario) you get double audio. Windows 7 allows the app to disable the local sound (so you'd only get the sound thru the app and NOT through Windows).

I have NOT found a solution that allows RECORDING audio through the ipad to the PC.

Answer (score 1):

The only rdp client I know of that records through the iPad onto the host is "iRDP AV".  The only problem is it doesn't have the functionality that many other RDP apps have such as two-finger scrolling, etc.  It's only 2.99 though and definitely worth it if you just need basic desktop control and mic functionality.

Answer (score 0):

LogMeIn Ignition is a great app for remotely accessing a variety of desktops.

You need to install an app on the target host but with this you can use the Ignition iPhone/iPad app (non-free) and browser app (free) as you wish. There is a free and paid subscription for the LogMeIn product, the paid version gives you sound I believe and the ability to send/receive files.

http://logmein.com